# Removes element in language url

Tags: nginx, redirect

Currently I have a multilingual PHP website and have the following URL structure: `https://qrcodeaz.com/?lang=vi`.
Now I want to remove the element `?lang=` from the URL and only leave: `https://qrcodeaz.com/vi`.
I use Nginx, please help me with the code. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code (before any of the `location` blocks):

```
    if ($args ~ (.*)(^|&)lang=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
        set $lang $arg_lang;
        set $args $1$3$4;
    }
    if ($lang) {
        rewrite (.*) /$lang$1;
    }
```

Please note that this code would not generate HTTP redirect, `https://qrcodeaz.com/?lang=vi` URL will be served as `https://qrcodeaz.com/vi` transparently to end user. If you want to generate HTTP 301/302 redirects, use `rewrite (.*) /$lang$1 permanent;` for HTTP 301 redirection or `rewrite (.*) /$lang$1 redirect;` for HTTP 302 redirection.